# Symfony : how can i add a post validator without overriding the existing ones?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony1, sfguard

I'm using sfGuard plugin, and the register form by default has a few post validators (for username and email).

I googled alot and haven't found any methods/hacks for adding post validators without having to rewrite them all...

Because when I do:

```
   $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
      new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'checkPassword')))
    );
```

all the other post validators seem to disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$this->mergePostValidator(
  new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'checkPassword')))
);
```